# Simulation of P(X + Y < 1) in matlab

Tags: probability, statistics, matlab, simulation

I am trying to solve the following problem, but I do not know how to go about it.

> Let $X \sim \mathcal{U}(0;1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{Exp}(1)$ be independent. Simulate in MATLAB how you can find the probability $\mathbb{P}[X + Y < 1]$.

Thank you.

Comment: Something like: take a large sample of $X$; take a similarly large sample of $Y$; add them together pointwise; find the proportion of the sums that are less than $1$. In R you could try something like `X<-runif(10^6);Y<-rexp(10^6,1);mean(X+Y<1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have learned that $-\ln(U)$ where $U$ is uniform on $(0;1)$ follows an $\mathcal{Exp}(1)$ law. Therefore, it will be a privilegized way to simulate such a distribution.

Here is a Matlab program that gives the result :

> ```
> n=100000;
> X=rand(1,n);
> Y=-log(rand(1,n));
> Z=X+Y;
> U=Z<1;
> P=mean(U)
> hist(Z,60);% optional !
> ```

($Z$ is a boolean array with entries $0$ (resp. $1$) if the condition is not fulfilled (resp. fulfilled) ;  the number of "ones" is the number of successes).

> The numerical result $P \approx 0.3678$ coincides very well with the theoretical result $e^{-1}$...

... that can be computed using the underlying density of Random Variable $Z=X+Y$ which is the convolution of the densities of $X$ and $Y$, i.e. :

$$(\text{for} \  x>0) : \ \ f_Z(x)=e^{-x}(e^{-min(x,1)}-1)$$

Here is a histogram of the simulation of  $Z$ :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.